# How to get a record from within custom visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

If I have a custom controller and a custom visualforce page, and I'm passing an ID as a query param, how can I get the associated record for that ID from within the VF page?

```
public class MyCustomController() {
  ... legacy code here
}

<apex:page controller="MyCustomController">
  <apex:outputText value="{! SOME VF SYNTAX TO RETRIEVE RECORD GIVEN QUERY PARAM ID}" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to take advantage of the `StandardController`. You don't even need `Apex`, although you can extend functionality with it.

**Markup**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="MyExtension>
    <apex:outputText value="{!Account.Name}" />
</apex:page>
```

**Code**

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
    public Account record { get; private set; }
    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // call controller.addFields for any data you need
        // if it is not used anywhere in your markup
        record = (Account)controller.getRecord();
    }
}
```

If you cannot use `StandardController` for some reason, you should query down a `List<SObject>`, because you don't know if the query will return any results.

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
    public Account record { get; private set; }
    public MyExtension()
    {
        // parameter name below is CASE SENSITIVE
        String id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        List<Account> candidates = [SELECT ... FROM Account WHERE Id = :id LIMIT 1];
        if (!candidates.isEmpty()) record = candidates[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can it be done without a StandardController? For example, I have multiple objects I'm looking at in a custom controller that cannot be re-written (legacy code). So is there VF syntax that can get a single object given an ID? Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisFellows You need `Apex`, something similar to my second example. You can put that code in an extension even if you must use a custom controller, so as to preserve the legacy code (and not need to muck around with it). I just realized I didn't use the empty constructor in the second example...amended that.

Comment: Ok fair enough. Thought there might be a VF direct solution here. But understood. Thanks for that.

Comment: @ChrisFellows Nope, you need `SOQL` and you can only access it from `Apex`.