# How to Fetch records of Sobject from custom controller in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Like in standard controller we can fetch objects records like:
standardcontroller="account";
{!account.name};

how we can fetch from a custom controller?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a record from within custom visualforce page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114724/how-to-get-a-record-from-within-custom-visualforce-page)

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm) or the [Traihead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_custom_controllers)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Custom List Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_custom_list_controller.htm) as described in the Visualforce Developer Guide.

A custom list controller is similar to a standard list controller. Custom list controllers can implement Apex logic that you define to show or act on a set of records.

For example you can create the following custom list controller based on a SOQL query:

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="opportunityList2Con">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opportunities}" var="o">
            <apex:column value="{!o.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!o.CloseDate}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller

```
public class opportunityList2Con {
    // ApexPages.StandardSetController must be instantiated
    // for standard list controllers
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
        get {
            if(setCon == null) {
                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                    [SELECT Name, CloseDate FROM Opportunity]));
            }
            return setCon;
        }
        set;
    }

    // Initialize setCon and return a list of records
    public List<Opportunity> getOpportunities() {
        return (List<Opportunity>) setCon.getRecords();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @saroj bera, thank u for ur reply, as here you are using standard object(Opportunity) directly, I have to pass the sobject Dyanamically so in that case what I have to do, thanks in advance.